# Change Drupal URL

Tags: uri, files

I use cpanel and ftp (filezila)

I don't know much about drupal. I believe i am using v.6

I have an old website made in drupal: www.oldwebsite.com

I don't want to delete my oldwebsite but change to www.oldwebsite.com/drupal
So I have then www.oldwebsite.com free to put whatever.

Easy?

How and where do i acess the files to change such a thing? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe in order to switch Drupal from using no sub directory to instead use on, you only need to:

1. Copy all of the files into the sub directory e.g. /drupal. This can be done with FTP (or SSH)
2. Edit the file [.htaccess](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x:/.htaccess) and uncomment the line 103(`RewriteBase /drupal`). Make sure the rewrite base is the same as the name you gave your subfolder above
3. Optional extra, ensure all your content is linked correctly as any hard coded links in content are will now no longer work, or better yet, use a module like [pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) to ensure links never break